# Checkar parametro no URL e disparar função javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boas pessoal, a minha ideia é ver se o parametro [bust] no URL é igual a "success" e se for quero mudar a class dos `<a>` mas só durante 5segundos, depois desse tempo removo a class (neste caso disabled)..

```js
<script>
var bust = location.search.split('bust=')[1];
if(bust==success){
        $(".click").addClass("disabled");
setInterval(function(){
    $(".click").removeClass("disabled");
}, 5000);       
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso ajude

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const busted = urlParams.get('bust');

if(busted === 'success') {
   $('.click').addClass('disabled');
   setTimeout(() => {
      $('.click').removeClass('disabled');
   }, 5000)
}
```

Usamos a interface **URLSearchParams** para poder trabalhar com as query string da url.

Com ela podemos passar a url, que no caso é `location.search` e usamos o método `get()` para recuperar os valores da query string.

Após isso faz-se a verificação desejada, adiciona a classe e usa-se o `setTimeout` para remover a class depois de cinco segundos.

Nesse caso você vai usar o `setTimeout()` pois se colocar `setInterval()` ele vai executar sempre dentro daquele intervalo, é algo contínuo. Já o `setTimeout()` executa apenas uma vez após o intervalo.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

Answer (score 0):

Definição e Uso
O método setInterval () chama uma função ou avalia uma expressão em intervalos especificados (em milissegundos).

O método setInterval () continuará chamando a função até que clearInterval () seja chamado ou a janela seja fechada.

O valor do ID retornado por setInterval () é usado como parâmetro para o método clearInterval ().

Dica: 1000 ms = 1 segundo.

Dica: Para executar uma função apenas uma vez, após um número especificado de milissegundos, use o método setTimeout () .

var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 3000);
}

function alertFunc() {
  alert("Hello!");
}

(o método setInterval () executará a função uma vez a cada 1 segundo, como um relógio digital):

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}